# D3.js How to update a global variable from d3.select()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, slider, global-variables, local-variables

I'm stuck with a global/local variable issue.
Here, my code based on http://www.d3noob.org/2014/04/using-html-inputs-with-d3js.html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Input test (circle)</title>
    <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
          <label for="nRadius" 
             style="display: inline-block; width: 240px; text-align: right">
             radius = <span id="nRadius-value">…</span>
          </label>
          <input type="range" min="1" max="150" id="nRadius">
        </p>
        <script src="./slider.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

slider.js

```
// update the circle radius
function update(nRadius) {
    // adjust the text on the range slider
    d3.select("#nRadius-value").text(nRadius);
    d3.select("#nRadius").property("value", nRadius);

    // update the circle radius
    circle.selectAll("circle").attr("r", nRadius);
    return nRadius;
    }

var width = 600;
var height = 300;     
var circle = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)    
            .attr("height", height);

// Circle with no radius
circle.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 300)
      .attr("cy", 150) 
      .style("fill", "none")   
      .style("stroke", "blue");

// Initial radius 
update(50);

// when the input range changes update the circle 
d3.select("#nRadius").on("input", function() {
    update(+this.value);
    });
```

This code works just fine, but what I'd like to do is to be able to export 'this.value' outside the d3.select, in order to use it in some other function.

The d3.select showed below already includes some suggestions found by googling my question:

```
var currentRadius = 0;
d3.select("#nRadius").on("input", function() {
    currentRadius = +this.value
    console.log("Inside: " + currentRadius);
    currentRadius = update(currentRadius);
    });

console.log("Outside: " + currentRadius);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
//this is your global variable
var currentRadius = 0;

d3.select("#nRadius").on("input", function() {
    //you are changing the global value here on change event.
    currentRadius = +this.value
    console.log("Inside: " + currentRadius);
    currentRadius = update(currentRadius);
    //call your function 
    outside();
    });
//some function somewhere
function outside(){
   console.log(currentRadius)
}
//value of global variable when this executed is 0 
//because no change event has been called
console.log("Outside: " + currentRadius);
```

So in short the global variable change will happen in the change function.
And the `console.log("Outside: " + currentRadius);` is done much before that event got fired.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Cyril. Your answer makes perfect sense. My question is : is there a way to update the global variable at the same time the event occurs, in order to use it in some other function (outside the d3.select) ?

Comment: well you change the global variable  inside the change event like this currentRadius = update(currentRadius); then you call your method from there. In my example above i am calling some function outside()