# D3 dynamically updating hierarchical edge bundling with slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've implemented a hierarchical edge bundle in D3.v3 and am having trouble getting the plot to update based on my slider. I have correlation coefficients in my data which I filter on when sliding the bar, but it only updates in one direction. Any help with this would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

I've tried many similar examples online, such as these ones to update the data : http://www.d3noob.org/2014/04/using-html-inputs-with-d3js.html, [D3.js How to update a global variable from d3.select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199485/d3-js-how-to-update-a-global-variable-from-d3-select), but it hasn't helped resolve my problem.

I also have my code working on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/transcend2030/9gzrc2bw/378/

```
var diameter = 960,
radius = diameter / 2,
innerRadius = radius - 120;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, innerRadius]);

var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
        .interpolate("bundle")
        .tension(.85)
        .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
        .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

var canvas = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")
      .append("g");

updateBundle(flareData);

function updateBundle(data) {

  var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(data));
  var links = packageImports(nodes);

    var link = canvas.selectAll(".link").data(bundle(links));
  var node = canvas.selectAll(".node").data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }));

  link.enter().append("path");

  //link.transition().duration(500);

  link.each(function(d) { d.source = d[0]
                                        , d.target = d[d.length - 1]
                        , d.link_color = d.source.link_colors[d.target.keyname]
                        , d.link_weight = d.source.link_weights[d.target.keyname]; })
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", line)
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.link_color; });

    node.enter().append("text");

  //node.transition().duration(500);

  node.attr("class", "node")
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.node_color; })
        .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
        .on("mouseout", mouseouted);

  node.exit().remove();
  link.exit().remove();

    function mouseovered(d) {
    node
        .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

    link
        .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
        .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
            .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
        .each(function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })

    node
        .classed("node--both", function(n) { return n.source && n.target; })
        .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
        .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
    }

    function mouseouted(d) {
    link
        .classed("link--target", false)
        .classed("link--source", false);

    node
        .classed("node--both", false)
        .classed("node--target", false)
        .classed("node--source", false);
    }

    //d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

    function packageHierarchy(classes) {
        var map = {};

        function find(keyname, data) {
            var node = map[keyname], i;
            if (!node) {
            node = map[keyname] = data || {keyname: keyname, children: []};
            if (keyname.length) {
                node.parent = find(keyname.substring(0, i = keyname.lastIndexOf("#")));
                node.parent.children.push(node);
                node.key = keyname.substring(i + 1);
            }
            }
            return node;
        }

        classes.forEach(function(d) {
            find(d.keyname, d);
        });

        return map[""];
    }

    function packageImports(nodes) {
        var map = {}, imports = [];

        nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            map[d.keyname] = d;
        });

        nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
            imports.push({source: map[d.keyname], target: map[i]});
            });
        });

        return imports;
    }
}

d3.select("input[type=range]").on("change", function() {

  //d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();

  updateBundle(flareData);

  var FlareData = eval(filterData(+this.value));



  updateBundle(FlareData);

});

function filterData(thresh) {

    //let flData = eval(Object.assign([], flareData));

    var FlareData = []
  var data = []
    var allImports = []

  //Remove nodes from imports with weight below threshold
  for (var i = 0; i < flareData.length; i++) {
    var flare = flareData[i];

    var link_weights = flare.link_weights;
    var link_colors = flare.link_colors;
    var imports = flare.imports;

    var newLink_weights = {};
    var newLink_colors = {};
    var newImports = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(link_weights)) {

        if (value > (thresh / 100)) {
            newLink_weights[key] = value;
          newLink_colors[key] = link_colors[key];
          newImports.push(key);
          allImports.push(key);
        }
        }

    flare.link_weights = newLink_weights;
    flare.link_colors = newLink_colors;
    flare.imports = newImports;

    data.push(flare)
    }

  //Remove nodes with no links
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    var flare = data[j];

    var keyName = flare.keyname;

    var index = allImports.indexOf(keyName)

    if (index >= 0) {
        FlareData.push(flare)
    }
  }

  return FlareData;
}
```

Comment: on line 8359 you modify your original data

Comment: Don't make dicts with links and colors but group data together in records in ONE dictionary, filtering data will be much simpler

Comment: what is the purpose of **eval** in `eval(filterData(+this.value));` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. That fixed it. I thought I had made a deep copy of the data before modifying it. I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and D3. I've also taken your other suggestions onboard and made the changes.